# Sidebar Thumbs Squished?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

My Thumbnails seem squished for some reason even though I copied the code from some thumbnails I have that seem to be working fine.

The code that works:

in index.php

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb',array('title' => "")); ?>
</a>
```

in functions.php

```
//Main Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 192, 134 );
}
```

The thumbs above work fine, resizing the main image to 192x134 without a problem.

The code below does not work.

in sidebar.php

```
<li>
    <a class="sidebar-thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'sidebar-thumb',array('title' => "")); ?></a>       
    <a class="sidebar-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>      
</li>
```

in functions.php

```
//Sidebar Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'sidebar-thumb', 47, 47 );
}
```

What did I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to regenerate all thumbnails. The name of the plugin is "regenerate thumbnails" for those that may run into a similar issue